# Perl regex get string with quoted text inside quotes

Tags: regex, perl, escaping

I'm writing a command line interpreter but i'm blank on this type of input:

```
command -text "hello this is "some text" with "quotes inside"" -other "another thing""" -another " -another "text"
```

I need to escape the quotes and then input the string into my parser.
What i thought:

`/".+"/` but it takes everything from the first quote.

Do you have any insights?

EDIT:
What i want:

input: `command -text "hello this is "some text" with "quotes inside"" -other "another thing""" -another " -another "text"`

output: `command -text "hello this is \"some text\" with \"quotes inside\"" -other "another thing\"\"" -another " -another \"text"`

Comment: Can you write the result expected or the string quoted?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use quotes both as a command line argument delimiter and a valid character within those same arguments (at least not without escaping it). Your quotes aren't balanced, but otherwise what you'd get on any sane system is a string concatenated at joining quotes.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. How is the interpreter to know that `"hello this is "some text" with "quotes inside""` is a single string with quotes inside, rather than three quoted strings intermingled with some unquoted ones?

Comment: i want the regex to take the most extreme quotes and then escape all that's inside

Comment: Are you sending the example input to Perl through some shell? If so, your input probably isn't what you think it is by the time Perl sees it.

Comment: The problem is that your command is not getting the quote (`"`) characters.

Comment: @flesk and what do you suggest for inputting text without escaped characters as parameters?

Comment: can you use module String-ShellQuote  for this purpose? http://search.cpan.org/~rosch/String-ShellQuote-1.03/ShellQuote.pm

Comment: @alfa64: Re: "i want the regex to take the most extreme quotes and then escape all that's inside": Pardon me, but I don't think you do; if you did, your output would have many more backslashes: `command -text "hello this is \"some text\" with \"quotes inside\"\" -other \"another thing\"\"\" -another \" -another \"text"`. No?

Comment: @alfa64: That depends on how you expose that command to Perl. If it's just text read from file or `STDIN` `/"(.+)"/` should work as you expect it to, but there's no auto escape of quotes. Otherwise, you need to escape those quotes before passing it to Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have a VERY ugly solution... It handles everything but dashes within strings.

Hope your eyes don't get hurt...

```
fg@erwin ~ $ perl -ne 'my @l; foreach (split /-/) { my ($start, $middle, $end) = m/^([^"]+)"(.*)"([^"]*)$/ or do { push @l, $_; next; }; $middle =~ s/"/\\"/g;push @l, "$start\"$middle\"$end"; } END { print join("-", @l) . "\n";}' <<EOF
> command -text "hello this is "some text" with "quotes inside"" -other "another thing""" -another " -another "text"
> EOF
command -text "hello this is \"some text\" with \"quotes inside\"" -other "another thing\"\"" -another " -another "text"
```

Explaining it a little...

```
my @l;  # declare a new list l, which will contain the "transformed" strings
foreach (split /-/) {  # split against the dash -- no loop variable: $_ has the content
    # Try and capture in start, middle and end:
    # * start: from the beginning until the first quote;
    # * middle: everything but the last quote and whatever is after it;
    # * end: what is after the last quote
    # By default, m// applies to $_
    my ($start, $middle, $end) = m/^([^"]+)"(.*)"([^"]*)$/
        or do { # if no match...
            push @l, $_;  # put the line as is,
            next;         # and continue
        };
    $middle =~ s/"/\\"/g; # in the middle part, precede all quotes with a \
    push @l, "$start\"$middle\"$end"; # and push the final string onto the list
}

# finally, print all transformed lines joined with a dash, plus a newline
END { print join("-", @l) . "\n";}
```

Comment: yes it's ugly and i can barely understand it but you seem to be onto something

Comment: You actually have a missed single double quote `"` in the last segment. `"text"` should be `\"text"`. There is no way to avoid quoted dashes `-` with a simple split.

Comment: @TLP yes, as I said, dashes within strings are the only thing this program misses, and I see now way around it -- not even using a grammar

Answer (score 4):

You are going down a bad path, IMO. You need some definitive way to delimit the arguments. If you want to allow chaos in the arguments, you need something else to bring order.

In other words, you could use something like

```
-label1 [random characters] -nextlabel [random characters]
```

But that would still mean that you could not use dash `-` in some combinations, as using `-text "some random -text"` would break it.

It sounds to me like you want an fool-proof solution to compensate for users who don't know what they are doing. Automation will lead you wrong, though. Just write an air tight command parser, and give an error when strings are improperly quoted. Let the users correct their input, not you.

Comment: yes, this pretty much describes my problem but you can't blame me for idiot proofing :)

Comment: @alfa64 The problem is that you would not know when they were being idiots and not. Just let them enter `-text "yada "yada" yada" -other ..` and return `yada: Command not found`.